# python: determine if all entries of a list are within entry of a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list such as:

```
>>l = [[['bcsA', 'F'], ['bcsB', 'F'], ['bcsC', 'R']], [['bcsE', 'R'], ['bcsF', 'R']]]
>>n = [['GROUP A'], [[['bcsQ', 'F'], ['bcsA', 'F'], ['bcsB', 'F'], ['bcsZ', 'F'], ['bcsC', 'F']], [['yhjK', 'R']], [['yhjK', 'F']], [['bcsC', 'R'], ['bcsZ', 'R'], ['bcsB', 'R'], ['bcsA', 'R'], ['bcsQ', 'R']], [['bcsC', 'F'], ['bcsZ', 'F'], ['bcsB', 'F'], ['bcsA', 'F'], ['bcsQ', 'F']]]], 
      [[['GROUP A'], [[['bcsA', 'F'], ['bcsB', 'F'], ['bcsC', 'R']], [['bcsE', 'R'], ['bcsF', 'R']], [['yhjK', 'F']]]],
```

So what I was hoping to do is if the nested lists `[['bcsA', 'F'], ['bcsB', 'F'], ['bcsC', 'R']]` and `[['bcsE', 'R'], ['bcsF', 'R']]` were found in the same list in the other nested list then it would give me the first entry.

the output would, hopefully, be `GROUP B`.

The list `l` will be different each time I go through the program.

I have tried a bunch of variations of:

```
>>>for x in n:
>>>    if all(e in x for e in l):
>>>         print n[n.index(x)][0]
```

I think what it is doing is if the individual items in the nested list of `l` are anywhere in `n` then it will give me that they are in GROUP A but really the output should be GROUP B.
I have tried it without the `all()` statement as well. I feel like this is a simple thing but I cannot figure it out. I hope this makes sense. Thank you for any help!

tl;dr:
How to tell if all values of a list are contained within a nested list and if so, print the first entry of the nested list.

Comment: why do You use braces here `if [all(e in x for e in l)]`? I mean why not all(e in x for e in l)

Comment: @Binnie, can you format your code properly ?

Comment: @Binnie, and can You make Your example shorter and easier for reading?

Comment: @Oz123, I'm not sure if that is any better. I really don't know what I am doing.. Sorry..

Comment: How do you get those lists ? What is the higher level problem ? I feel like lists of lists of lists is not a very effective Data Structure

Answer (score 0):

I think One Should remember that both `bool([False]) == True` and `bool([True]) == True` so when construction `[any(...)]:` is used Any one can tells for sure that this statement will be `True`